# Find My iPad setting prevents restore

Tags: itunes, ipad, icloud, find-my-iphone

I'm trying to restore my iPad because the screen passcode was changed and cannot be remembered correctly. When attempting to restore from an iTunes backup, an error message says to first turn off **Find My iPad** in iCloud settings. I cannot access any setting in the iPad because of the screen lock passcode. Is there another way to do a reset or full factory reset while screen-locked?

Answer (score 7):

Try setting the iPad in recovery mode:

1. connect the iPad to your computer
2. turn it completely off
3. press the power button (top button) for three (3) seconds
4. without letting go of the power button, press the Home button
5. keep them pressed for ten (10) seconds
6. after the ten seconds, let go of the power button *without letting go of the Home button*
7. keep pressing the Home button until a message pops in iTunes saying

   > iTunes has detected a device in recovery mode, you must restore it before you can use it.
8. restore the iPad

Try doing this a few times if you dont succeed the first time.

Comment: This is what worked for me, though I had to try a couple of times -- both the press-and-hold for booting into recover mode, and doing factory restore in itunes. The first attempt failed with "unknown error 4005" from itunes.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off **Find my iPhone** by logging in to [icloud.com](https://www.icloud.com/) from your computer if your iPad is offline (not connected to the Internet).

If it's online, first turn off the iPad completely (press and hold the power button until the **slide to power off** prompt appears, then tap and slide on the prompt to power it off).

To turn off **Find my iPhone** on your iPad, follow these steps on the Apple support page [iCloud: Remove your device](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2702):

> ### Remove your device from Find My iPhone
>
> 1. Sign in to [icloud.com/#find](http://www.icloud.com/#find) with your Apple ID (the one you use with iCloud).
>      If you’re already using an iCloud web app, click the app’s name to switch apps.
> 2. Click All Devices, select the offline device, then click Delete [image].
>
> The Delete icon appears only after Find My iPhone has tried and failed to connect to your device (this may take a few minutes).
>
> Note:   You can also click “Remove from Find My iPhone” in the device’s Info window.
>
> 3. Click Remove.

Comment: I followed these steps to remove device from (Find My iPhone) after loging into iCloud. iCloud now reports 'No Devices'. The iPad still will not do a reset in iTunes. The same error displays "Find My iPad must be turned off... go to iCloud settings on your iPad..." Is there some other way to do a reset on this thing?

Comment: I get same result as @stepjo, removing ipad in icloud settings from icloud website does not make the message go away. Also tried full power off cycle.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem; none of the suggested fixes worked.

I used voice commands to disable "voice over". This allowed the unit to unlock.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to set up or use voice commands?